# Change basis from $\{1,x,x^2, \dots,x^n\}$ to $\{1,x-a,\dots,(x-a)^n\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Problem:** Change basis from $\{1,x,x^2, \dots,x^n\}$ to $\{1,x-a,\dots,(x-a)^n\}$

My attempt: $1=1$, $x=x-0a$, $x^2=x^2 - 0xa - 0a^2$, $\dots$, $x^n=x^n -0x^{n-1} \dots 0$. So the matrix of changing from $\{1,x,x^2, \dots,x^n\}$ to $\{1,x-a,\dots,(x-a)^n\}$

\begin{matrix} 1 \quad 0 \quad  \dots 0 \\ 1 \quad 0 \quad  \dots 0 \\ 1 \quad 0 \quad  \dots 0 \\ \dots \\ 1 \quad 0 \quad  \dots 0
 \end{matrix}

Is that right???

Comment: That is not right. For one thing, your matrix should depend on $a$. Observe that $x-a=(-a)\cdot 1+1\cdot x$, $(x-a)^2=a^2\cdot 1-2a\cdot x+1\cdot x^2$, etc.

Comment: A change of basis matrix must be nonsingular (determinant != 0), for one.  Try using the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the change-of-basis matrix you wrote says that the first element in the basis $\{1,x,x^2,\dots,x^n\}$ (i.e., $1$) is
$$1\cdot 1 + 1\cdot(x-a)+1\cdot(x-a)^2+\cdots+1\cdot(x-a)^n$$
while the rest of the elements in the basis are all $0$. Clearly this isn't the case.

Furthermore, you have not written the elements of the basis $\mathcal{B}_1=\{1,x,x^2,\dots,x^n\}$ in terms of the basis $\mathcal{B}_2=\{1,(x-a),(x-a)^2,\dots,(x-a)^n\}$. You write, for instance, $x = x-0a$, but $x-0a$ is not an element of $\mathcal{B}_2$. Instead, you should have $x=a\cdot 1 + 1 \cdot(x-a)$, since $1$ and $x-a$ are elements of $\mathcal{B}_2$.

In general, you need to know how to write $x^k$ as a linear combination of elements of $\mathcal{B}_1$. To do this, as Jair Taylor suggested in the comments, write $x^k=((x-a)+a)^k$ and use the [Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) to expand.

Comment: You can also use $x^n = ((x-a) +a)^n$ and expand to write $x^n$ in terms of $(x-a)^k$.

Comment: @JairTaylor Good point, I will edit my answer since that is easier than inverting an $n \times n$ matrix with entries involving $a$!